# How to call a bash script with positional parameters?

Tags: bash, parameters

I have a script which will be executed using the below command,

```
bin/nutch crawl urls -dir /data/test/
```

bin/nutch - Script file
crawl, urls, /data/test/ - Parameters
-dir - Option

The above script should executed from a shell script named test.sh. I have the below code to execute it, but it fails to pass the positional parameters,

```
path="/home/vel/vel-home/scripting/apache-nutch-1.6/bin"
. $path/nutch "crawl" -dir "$path/urls" "$path/data/test/"
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: is "/data/test/" a parameter to option "-dir"? Or is -dir a boolean option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `$1`, `$2` and so on, in order to access arguments passed to your script.

Here is an example script:

```
NUTCH_HOME="/home/vel/vel-home/scripting/apache-nutch-1.6"
dataDir="$1"
${NUTCH_HOME}/bin/nutch crawl "${NUTCH_HOME}/urls" -dir "$dataDir"
```

You would run it like this: `myscript.sh /data/test`

Comment: Thanks. Ideally positional parameters should be come first and then 'options' should feed to the script.